# Reading and rewriting a HttpResponse in a webservice

Tags: c#, httpresponse

I've got a 3rd party library (C#/.NET) of which I cannot modify the source code. This 3rd party library has a method which I call that writes directly to the HttpResponse object of my webmethod. The response contains a status code. This response is returned to the client and all is well.

However, now I'm interested in finding out what status code the method has written to the response object. I want to know this before returning the response to the client and, if necessary, rewrite the response as I see fit.

So my question is basically if there's a way for me to read the contents of the response object and overwrite it as well? And just to be clear: I'm talking about a response that the server is sending back to the client, not a response that is received by the server as the result of a request it did.

Comment: is there any method/API you are calling ? Do you have response object returned from library? or is it registered HttpHandler on asp.net server? can u show some code?

Comment: Hi, I defined my own webmethod which basically consists of nothing more than a call to one method in the library. I pass my Response object to this method. The method builds an XmlDocument and then calls xml.Save(response.OutputStream) to write the XML to the output stream. I would like to be able to know in my own webmethod what xml was written to the response object.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the `HttpResponse` object you can get and set the the status code with the `StatusCode` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx

You can also modify other properties like the `Body` and then once you've made the changes that you'd like call `BeginFlush()` to send the buffered response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Check by registering HttpModule and implementing events. Pasting reference links for your help.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30907/The-Two-Interceptors-HttpModule-and-HttpHandlers
http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2008/03/03/web-page-optmisation-using-httpmodule.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx